# Как скомпилировать программу или библиотеку для x11 и wayland одновременно?

Tags: linux, sdl, sdl2, x11, wayland

Я не пойму как сделана библиотека SDL2, изучать её трудно, всё равно не пойму где там логика работы о том, что будет вызываться. Например если я скомпилирую с помощью SDL2 проект в x11 среде, то он же будет работать в wayland? Но возможно у меня когда собирался SDL2, он не подключал wayland. Как же тогда это всё работает?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых в SDL реализованы независимые прослойки для работы с X11 и wayland. В терминолигии SDL они называются драйверы и находятся в папках `./src/video/x11` и `./src/wayland`. Если просто собрать в x11 среде, то wayland драйвер просто не будет участвовать в сборке. Соответственно надо позаботиться, чтобы заголовочные файлы wayland были доступны при сборке. Затем при работе приложения можно указать требуемые драйвер при вызове `SDL_VideoInit` - все функции драйвера ресолвятся в рантайме. Если драйвер не указан, то используется значение из переменной окружения `SDL_VIDEODRIVER`. Если совсем ничего нет, то инициализация происходит перебором всех доступных драйверов.

Определить, с какими драйверами собран проект, можно используя функции `SDL_GetVideoDriver` и `SDL_GetNumVideoDrivers`.